# Dynamically Load HTML page using Polymer importHref

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm writing a simple element that loads html files using Polymer 1.0's helper function `importHref()`. The page loads in, but instead of the html rendering to the page, I'm getting `[object HTMLDocument]`.

When I log the successful callback, the imported page is wrapped in a `#document` object (not sure on the terminology here). But, the info is all there in the console.

So, my question is: How do I render the html to the page?

element:

```
<dom-module id="content-loader">

<template>
    <span>{{fileContent}}</span>
</template>

<script>

Polymer({

    is: "content-loader",

    properties: {
        filePath: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.loadFile();
    },

    loadFile: function() {
        var baseUrl;

        if (!window.location.origin)
        {
            baseUrl = window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
        }
        else
        {
            baseUrl = window.location.origin;
        }

        //import html document and assign to fileContent
        if(this.filePath)
        {
            this.importHref(baseUrl + this.filePath, function(file){
                this.fileContent = file.target.import;
                console.log(this.fileContent); //logs fine
            },
            function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }

});

</script>
```

in use:

```
<content-loader file-path="/app/general/contact.html"></content-loader>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<span>{{fileContent}}</span>` will render `fileContent` cast to a String, which is why you see `[object HTMLDocument]` (which is what you get when you call `toString()` on a `document` Object).

Just in general, Polymer won't let you bind to HTML or node content because it's a security risk.

The `fileContent` you have is a `document`, which means it's a collection of DOM nodes. How you use that document depends on what the content is that you loaded. One way to render the nodes is to append `fileContent.body` onto your local DOM, like so:

`Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(this.fileContent.body);`

Here is a more complete example (http://jsbin.com/rafaso/edit?html,output):

```
<content-loader file-path="polymer/bower.json"></content-loader>

<dom-module id="content-loader">

  <template>
    <pre id="content"></pre>
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({
      is: "content-loader",
      properties: {
        filePath: {
          type: String,
          observer: 'loadFile'
        }
      },

      loadFile: function(path) {
        if (this.filePath) {
          console.log(this.filePath);
          var link = this.importHref(this.filePath, 
            function() {
              Polymer.dom(this.$.content).appendChild(link.import.body);
            },
            function(){
              console.log("error");
            }
          );
        }
      }
    });

  </script>
</dom-module>
```